# GitLab CI and MsBuild (with tests)

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am in the process of migrating my svn repsitories to git with GitLab.

Now I have seen that there is a continuous integration implementation with GitLab CI and just want to try it out.

I already installed and configured a Runner but Gitlab complains that I don't have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

I already use TeamCity for continuous integration so I don't want to put too much effort into writing a build script.

Can anybody tell me where I can find a basic example of a `gitlab-ci.yml` file that basically just builds my Solution and runs all tests (MSTests)?

Comment: Checkout https://about.gitlab.com/2015/06/08/implementing-gitlab-ci-dot-yml/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apparently there is no simple msbuild example but this should get you started:

```
variables:
  Solution: MySolution.sln

before_script:
  - "echo off"
  - 'call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"'
  # output environment variables (usefull for debugging, propably not what you want to do if your ci server is public)
  - echo.
  - set
  - echo.

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo building...
  - 'msbuild.exe "%Solution%"'
  except:
  - tags

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - echo testing...
  - 'msbuild.exe "%Solution%"'
  - dir /s /b *.Tests.dll | findstr /r Tests\\*\\bin\\ > testcontainers.txt
  - 'for /f %%f in (testcontainers.txt) do mstest.exe /testcontainer:"%%f"'
  except:
  - tags

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo deploying...
  - 'msbuild.exe "%Solution%" /t:publish'
  only:
  - production
```

Figuring out which tests to run is a bit tricky. My convention is that every project has a folder tests in which the test projects are named after the schema MyProject.Core.Tests (for a project called MyProject.Core)

Just as a first feedback towards gitlab-ci

I like the simplicity and the source control integration. But I would like to be able to modify the script before execution (especially while changing the script) but I could imaging to rerun a specific commit and inject variables or change the script (I can do that with teamcity). Or even ignore a failed test and rerun the script again (I do that a lot with teamcity). I know gitlab-ci does not know anything about my tests I just have a command line that returns an error code.

Comment: how do you deal with failed tests.  gitlab-ci is showing that everything passes even when tests fail.

Comment: @Eric my solution has a little drawback. every test dll is run seperatly and overrides the exit code. So gitlab-ci.yml only knows about the exit code from the last test.
You can  either rewrite the code to exit if errorlevel > 0 or use `mstest.exe /testcontainer:MyProject.Core.Tests.dll /testcontainer:MyProject.Gui.Tests.dll` to run all tests in one test run.

Comment: @Eric That said: I switched to FAKE as a build system which is much more powerful and easy to use. My gitlab-ci.yml build steps only contain a single command `fake build` or `fake test`

It has build in commands for a different tasks

http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-mstest.html

Comment: What about running mono? How would it look like?

Comment: @MajesticRa Replace `msbuild.exe` with `xbuild` it should be compatible. If you are using the shell runner with bash instead of the windows cmd you can define variables with `BUILDTOOL=/path/to/xbuild` and use it like `$BUILDTOOL $SOLUTION`  
I don't know if mstest is supported but most likely you are using another test framework with mono.

Comment: Please consider submitting your example to the [GitLab CI Yml project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml/issues/12).

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to [Jürgen Steinblock answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991046/2501769), I would like to suggest a simplier alternative for the test stage script:

```
variables:
  SOLUTION_DIR: "MySolution"
  BUILD_DIR: "Release"
  TESTER: "vstest.console.exe" # or "mstest.exe /testcontainer:"

before_script:
  - call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32" # import in path tools like msbuild, mstest, etc using VS script

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - for /f %%F in ('dir /s /b %SOLUTION_DIR%\%BUILD_DIR%\*Tests.dll') do set dllPath=%%F
  - "%TESTER% %dllPath%"
```

This will launch testing on all test project binaries found which ends by convention with `*Tests.dll` in the build directory. This has the advantage of not using an intermediate file.

Comment: Thanks for the update, in my solution I had several projects in a "Test" directory which all build intependently, so there was no Directory with all `*Test.dll` - Directly invoking mstest from the `dir ... | finstr ...` did not work (can't remember why) thats why I used a file as a workaround. Anyway a long time has passed and my current solution would be: Use `.gitlab.ci file as little as possible and use `FAKE` as a build tool which has a nice `!! "Tests\**\bin\**\*.Tests.dll"  -- "Tests\ExludeThis\*" ++ ++ "IncludeThis\**\*.Tests.dll"` FileIncludes command and several nice commands

Comment: @JürgenSteinblock Thanks for the FAKE hint (lol), I will give a look to it. Yep indeed, I had the same problem. I guess it's because *gitlab-ce* runner API fails to correctly pass `\`` characters I guess. That's why, after a few tries, I end up using `'` to surround the *dir* command.

Comment: And please keep in mind that every new test run overrides the errorlevel. So your gitlab test stage fails only if the last test project failed (quite dangerous), look at the comment to my answer, the best solution is to run all tests at once `mstest.exe /testcontainer:MyProject.Core.Tests.dll /testcontainer:MyProject.Gui.Tests.dll`

Comment: Just remembered, that FAKE executes one test container after another, @cid this is taken from my build script, if you switch to FAKE, just putt the buildMSTestArgs2 and MSTest2 method in your script before the actual test target https://gist.github.com/Steinblock/2dd24006dab11d70fb5c4fccd03ad8c4

Comment: Agree about the potential danger. I actually use this because I don't know the exact name of the test dll but always has only one in the given folder so it's ok. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Please consider submitting your example to the [GitLab CI Yml project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml/issues/12).

Comment: @bbodenmiller I will, also consider upvoting if this helps you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used eventually. It runs all the *Tests.Dll in a single run.

```
  dir /s /b *.Tests.dll | findstr /r bin\\Debug > testcontainers.txt
  for /f %%x in (testcontainers.txt) do set list=!list! %%x
  set list=%list:~1%
  vstest.console.exe %list%
```

Answer (score 1):

Since things have changed a bit since this question has been opened (and now MS supports core/linux docker deployments right in VS), I thought I'd share my solution.

```
# Default image is docker:stable
image: docker:stable

# Define deployment stages
stages:
  - Test
  - Build

# We use docker-in-docker (dind) for building docker images (build stage)
services:
  - docker:dind

# Run unit test on dotnet core sdk image
test:
  stage: Test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  script:
    - dotnet restore "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Project.Tests/Project.Tests.csproj"
    - dotnet test "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Project.Tests/Project.Tests.csproj"
  tags: 
    - docker
  only:
    - master

# Only build when testing passes, build using Dockerfile/dind
build:
  stage: Build
  # Print docker instance details for logging/diagnosing
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
  script:
    - docker build -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest .
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest
  after_script:
    - docker logout ${CI_REGISTRY}
  tags: 
    - docker
  only:
    - master
  when: on_success
```

This should run the MS Unit tests on your solution, and if the tests pass, create an image from them (provided you have a Dockerfile next to the gitlab-ci.yml file). Ignore the build stage if you're *only* looking to perform unit testing automatically on commits.